# Outputting both stopped and Running processes in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ps

I'm presently using a Linux command in my c program to show a group of processes. When a process is stopped (suspended) though, this command does not list it. I need to list both running AND stopped jobs. **Note:** When I say stopped, I do NOT mean terminated jobs. The issue is with displaying suspended processes.

```
execvp("/bin/ps", parmList);
```

I have to use the ps command. Is there anyway to show both running and stopped (suspended) processes in this situation?

Comment: You can read the `proc` file system documentation in the linux kernel. Don't use `ps` in a c program, if you need to then you should probably write a shell script. Don't you ask yourself, how does `ps` do it?

Comment: @iharob No no, you're mistaken. I execute the command as part of a separate process. The command isn't actually used in C itself.

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood but from *I'm presently using the following Linux command in my c program to show a group of processes*, is what I can understand.

Comment: Your code is actually calling `ps` and doing it by assuming that it's path is `/bin/ps` which is one of the reasons why it's bad. Another reason is that maybe the environment where you intend to use the program lacks the `ps` utility. It would be uncommon but it's not impossible. And, you can always do what `ps` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about it:

1) Continuously monitor processes for change in state.

2) Register a handler to get notified asynchronously, when state changes.

> 1st case

execute a script that continously monitors process states.
You have to use ps with BSD style options ie

```
ps axo pid,stat
```

> 2nd case

you can only monitor the child processes.
you can monitor them by using `waitpid()` provided they are child processes.

So, basically you register a handler for signals and in the handler you use waitpid to get the status.

You will find the signals explained here:
[http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid][1]